# Extracting full name from Person or Group type?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can I get the fullname (firstname, lastname) of a user so I can place it in a email through a workflow. The only fields I can identify that might help are those of type Person or Group (Modifiedby, CreatedBy, etc.), but they all return domain/username. Any solution must be applicable to Sharepoint 2007.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but others may benefit from one possible solution.

IF you have a small & known user base, you can cross reference a secondary list that has (First, Last, Person (object)).  Set local variables in the workflow to first/last based on corresponding Person (as String or Display name typically) and reference in the dynamic email.  (Works for 2010, but am unable to verify for 2007)

Answer (score 0):

With Sharepoint 2010 you can choose how the workflow will return it (Name, email, username, etc), but not with Sharepoint 2007. So I think you're stuck with domain/username until you upgrade Sharepoint.

Comment: Seems to be the case, but I'm still researching, with no luck so far. Thanks.